# PHP Array Operator

Tags: php, arrays

I’m now learning PHP array but I have a question about the array operator. I saw an example when creating an array like this:

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array["a"] = "apple";
$array["b"] = "banana";
?>
```

Do I really need to declare the variable as `array` first?
Or can I just ignore the first line: `$array = array();`?

Comment: Resource: [strong and weak typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better yet, just initialize your array *and* assign values to it at the same time:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        "a" => "apple",
        "b" => "banana"
    );
?>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is to do it like your example. I don't have a specific reason or maybe because I read somewhere that writing like this $array[], is more preferable, is this true?

Comment: Doing it this way will save you a dozen or so keystrokes. @Joey - A better method I think.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to initialize your arrays in PHP. In other words, you don't need `$array = array();`, but it will save you code to do it like `@John Conde` showed.